# Nifi DetectDuplicate Not Detecting Duplicates

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the DetectDuplicate processor within a flow but am seeing some confusing behavior. The processor is configured as follows:

```
Cache Entry Identifier: ${rk.id}
FlowFile Description: Empty string set
Age Off Duration: 10s
Distributed Cache Service: DistributedMapCacheClientService
Cache The Entry Identifier: true
```

The "duplicate" relationship is automatically terminated. Concurrency is set to 1.

However, I'm seeing multiple copies of flowfiles on the output queue with the same `rk.id` that were run through the processor less than 2 seconds apart. How is this possible? I even tried increasing the age off to 5m and it made no difference. I also tried setting the processor to only run every 500ms, thinking there may be some delay in writing to the cache, and 2 flowfiles that were processed 1s apart with the same rk.id showed up in the output queue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. It looks like the cache was full and not accepting new values? Because we had a lot less traffic this morning and it seems to have properly run the deduplication.

Comment: I am having the same issue, I have a large number of entries going thru the cache. Current cache size is set to 100,000. I am going to expand it to 1M and see if this resolves the issue for me.